# Apache forward request to node webserver

Tags: apache, redirect, url-rewriting

I have apache2 server running on Debian.

The document root is in `/var/www/`, and my server is known as `http://myserver.net`.

I want to redirect (or rewrite) requests so `http://myserver.net/beta` maps to `http://myserver.net:3000/`, but end users still see `http://myserver.net/beta` in the browser's address bar.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

You want a [proxy rewrite rule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/proxy.html), something like this:

```
RewriteRule /beta/(.*) http://localhost:3000/$1 [P]
```

The client connects to Apache, and then Apache connects to your service running on port 3000, makes a request, and passes the response back to the client.  There is no client redirect here; the client only sees the original URL.